# Is numpy.save cross platform?

Tags: python, serialization, numpy, cross-platform

Suppose I save a numpy array to a file, "arr.npy", using numpy.save() and that I do this using a particular python version, numpy version, and OS.

Can I load, using numpy.load(), arr.npy on a different OS using a different version of python or numpy?  Are there any restrictions, such as backwards compatibility?

Comment: As an alternative proposal, a good way for serialization of numerical data is the hdf5 format e.g. with pytables. It is a well documented, platform independent with fast in access (e.g. partial matrices), language independent and respects endianness.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes.  The .npy format is documented here:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html#module-numpy.lib.format

Note this comment in the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/format.py) (emphasis mine):

> The `.npy` format is the standard binary file format in NumPy for
> persisting a *single* arbitrary NumPy array on disk. The format stores
> all of the shape and dtype information necessary to reconstruct the
> array correctly **even on another machine with a different architecture**.

Comment: Great, thanks.  It would be nice to get that added to the online docs here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html